# Finding $\small{\max\limits_{ab+bc+ca=3}\frac{ab}{2a+b}+\frac{bc}{2b+c}+\frac{ca}{2c+a}.}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, discriminant, uvw

Let $a,b,c \ge 0: ab+bc+ca=3.$ Find maximal value $$P=\frac{ab}{2a+b}+\frac{bc}{2b+c}+\frac{ca}{2c+a}.$$
My tryings lead to wrong inequality.

I tried to use C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{2a+b}\le \sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{9}\left(\frac{2}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{ab+bc+ca}{abc}=\frac{1}{abc}$$But $abc\le 1$ so we got reverse inequality.

Which a good approach is good here ? I am very appreciate for your helps.

Comment: Can you explain how you applied the Cauchy-Schwarz inequallity?  By definition it is $\sum{(u_kv_k)^2}\leq\left(\sum{u_k^2}\right)\left(\sum{v_k^2}\right)$. What are your $u_k$ and $v_k$?

Comment: @Veselin Dimov $\frac{1}{2a+b}\leq\frac{1}{(2+1)^2}\left(\frac{2^2}{2a}+\frac{1^2}{b}\right).$

Answer (score 4):

The maximum is $1$ when $a = b = c = 1$.

**Proof**.

We use isolated fudging.

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{ab}{2a + b} \le \frac{2ab + bc}{9}. \tag{1}$$
(*Note*: Taking cyclic sum on (1), we get
$\frac{ab}{2a+b}+\frac{bc}{2b+c}+\frac{ca}{2c+a} \le \frac{3(ab + bc + ca)}{9} = 1$.)

It suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 (2a + b)(2a + c) - 9a \ge 0
\end{align*}
or
$$4a^2 + 2ab + bc + 2ca - 9a \ge 0$$
or (using $ab + bc + ca = 3$)
$$4a^2 - 9a + 6 - bc \ge 0. \tag{2}$$

If $a \ge 1/4$, using $abc \le 1$ (by AM-GM),
we have
\begin{align*}
 a(4a^2 - 9a + 6 - bc)
 &= 4a^3 - 9a^2 + 6a - abc\\
 &\ge 4a^3 - 9a^2 + 6a - 1\\
 &= (4a - 1)(a - 1)^2\\
 &\ge 0.
\end{align*}

If $a < 1/4$, using $bc \le 3$, we have
$$4a^2 - 9a + 6 - bc
\ge -9\cdot \frac14 + 6 - 3 = \frac34 > 0. $$

We are done.

Comment: +1 Wow! It is so beautiful proof

Comment: @TATAbox Thanks.

Comment: How can someone come up with such a guess (1)? You saw the trick in a book. +1

Comment: @BobDobbs You can see Page 3 in [here](https://yufeizhao.com/olympiad/wc08/ineq.pdf)

Comment: @BobDobbs In detail, we want to find the form $\frac{ab}{2a + b} \le \frac{p_1a^r + p_2b^r + (1 - p_1 - p_2)c^r}{a^r + b^r + c^r}$. You can try the two special cases: $r = 1$ and $r = -1$. Here $r = -1$ works.

Comment: This is just puzzle solving....

Comment: @RiverLi Are you a teacher ? I read your document. It is very useful to train Math team.

Comment: @TATAbox I think it is not new. By the way, I am interested in difficult inequalities. For difficult inequalities, we usually rely on computer and hard to find a nice proof.

Comment: @RiverLi Very good point!

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to consider $a,b,c>0.$
Let $ab=u$, $bc=v$, $ca=w$ where $u+v+w=3$ and $u,v,w>0$, then
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{2a+b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{uvw}}{u+2v}\\\stackrel{Hölder}\leq\sqrt{3\sum_{cyc}\frac{uv}{(u+2v)^2}}\leq 1.$$
The last inequality follows from AM-GM. You may [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749576/maximum-of-sum-cyc-fracxyx2y2-x-y-z0-and-xyz-3) this question and their answers.

Comment: Why is downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote you. The maximum is $1$ when $a = b = c = 1$.

Comment: İ did a silly mistake in first version. But my solution now is not bad. Is it worthless? Or easy. @RiverLi

Comment: Did you provide a new solution?

Comment: It is incorrect that $\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{uvw}}{u+2v}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{uvw}{u+2v}}$, for example, $a = 2, b = 298/201, c = 1/100$ (then $u = 596/201, v = 149/10050, w = 1/50$).

Comment: Did you prove the last inequality?

Comment: @RiverLi Not yet. I am thinking about SOS inequality.

Comment: (+1) It is true.

Answer (score 1):

For $a=b=c=1$ we obtain a value $1$.

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$, where $v>0$, $abc=w^3$ and $u=tv$.

Thus, $v=1$, $t\geq1$ and we need to prove
$$\sum_{cyc}ab(2b+c)(2c+a)\leq\prod_{cyc}(2a+b)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2+7a^2bc)\leq v\sum_{cyc}(3abc+4a^2b+2a^2c)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2+7a^2bc)+v\sum_{cyc}(a^2c-a^2b)\leq v\sum_{cyc}(3abc+3a^2b+3a^2c)$$ or
$$18v^4-12uw^3+21uw^3+v(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\leq27uv^3$$ or
$$9(3uv^3-2v^4-uw^3)\geq v(a-b)(b-c)(c-a).$$
But by Maclaurin($u\geq v\geq w$) we see that $$3uv^3-2v^4-uw^3\geq0,$$ which says that it's enough to prove that:
$$81(3uv^3-2v^4-uw^3)^2\geq v^2\prod_{cyc}(a-b)^2$$ or
$$3(3uv^3-2v^4-uw^3)^2\geq v^2(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6)$$ or
$$(3u^2+v^2)w^6+2uv^2(2u^2-9uv+3v^2)+4v^6(6u^2-9uv+4v^2)\geq0,$$ which is obvious for $2u^2-9uv+3v^2\geq0.$

But for $2u^2-9uv+3v^2\leq0$ or $2t^2-9t+3\leq0$ it's enough to prove that:
$$t^2(2t^2-9t+3)^2-4(3t^2+1)(6t^2-9t+4)\leq0$$ or
$$(t-1)^2(16-4t+39t^2+28t^3-4t^4)\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$16-4t+39t^2+28t^3-4t^4\geq16-4t+45t^2+10t^3+2t^2(-2t^2+9t-3)\geq0.$$

Comment: +1 Does BW work ?

Comment: @TATA box I did not try.

Comment: A full expanding gives something easy, but it's  complicated enough.

Comment: I agree, we need to homogenize and squaring

Answer (score 1):

**Proof.**

We will prove $$\frac{ab}{2a+b}+\frac{bc}{2b+c}+\frac{ca}{2c+a}\le 3.$$
This inequality can be rewritten as $$\frac{2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)+7abc(a+b+c)}{(2a+b)(2b+c)(2c+a)}\le 3.$$Since $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2\ge abc(a+b+c),$ it suffices to prove $$\frac{3(ab+bc+ca)^2}{(2a+b)(2b+c)(2c+a)}\le 3,$$or $$(2a+b)(2b+c)(2c+a)\ge 27,$$
$$\iff 4\sum_{cyc}a^2b+2\sum_{cyc}ab^2+9abc\ge 27.\tag{*}$$
It is easily to show $$a+b+c\ge 3,$$$$\sum_{cyc}a^2b+\sum_{cyc}ab^2=3(a+b+c)-3abc,$$and $$(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=\sum_{cyc}ab^2-\sum_{cyc}a^2b.$$
Hence, we will prove stronger inequality according $(*)$ $$6(a+b+c)\ge 18+(a-b)(b-c)(c-a).\tag{**}$$
WLOG, assume that $a=\text{max}\{a,b,c.\}$

We can split $(**)$ into two cases

- $a\ge b\ge c.$ It means $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\le 0$ and $a+b+c\ge 3,$ so $(**)$ is true.
- $a\ge c\ge b.$ By the condition, $3=ab+bc+ca\ge 3b^2 \implies b\in [0;1].$

Now, rewrite $(**)$ as a function according $b$
$$\color{blue}{f(b)=(a-c)b^2+b(c^2-a^2-6)+ca^2-c^2a-6(a+c)+18\le 0.}$$Do a little with manipulation on function, the result follows.

Can you end it now ?

---

Indeed, we easily to see that$$f'(b)=2b(a-c)+c^2-a^2-6=(a-c)(2b-a-c)-6< 0.$$ It implies $f(b)$ is decreasing on $[0;1].$

Let $b=0; ca=3$, it is sufficient to prove $$f(0)\le 0 \iff ca(a-c)-6(a+c)+18\le 0.$$
$$\iff 3(a-c)-6(a+c)+18\le 0\iff a+3c\ge 6,$$which is true by AM-GM $a+3c\ge 2\sqrt{3ac}=6.$

It means $(**)$ is proven and we end proof here.

Comment: I scrolled down 3 pages. It still didn't end? :0

Comment: Can you tell more detail ? I didn't know what you mean ?

Comment: I am reading math.se posts on my phone. I tried to make a joke about this situation. I hope you are not offended.

Comment: Oh yeah, I don't mention it seriously.